# Pass user input from HTML to Flask with JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I have created a JS that creates 2 user input fields when a button is clicked that will then show on the html page. I want the 2 inputs to be passed once they are created into the flask application. I have everything in order but nothing seems to work.

Should I reference the input fields another way? I am very stuck and some guidance would be much appreciated.

[image]

Please find my code below

main.py

```
import sys
from flask import request, render_template, Flask, session, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hjshjhdjah kjshkjdhjs'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def inputNum():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        num1 = request.form.get("num0")
        session["num1"] = num1
        num2 = request.form.get("num1")
        session["num2"] = num2
        print(session["num1"])
        return redirect(url_for("results"))
    return render_template("inputNum.html")

@app.route('/results')
def results():
    if "num1" and "num2" in session:
        num1 = session["num1"]
        num2 = session["num2"]
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        log_file = open("message.log", "w")
        sys.stdout = log_file
        addNum(num1, num2)
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        log_file.close()
        with open("message.log", "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
        return app.response_class(content, mimetype='text/plain')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('inputNum'))

def addNum(num1, num2):
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    sum = num1 + num2
    print(sum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True)
```

inputFields.js

```
var num = 2; // ads 2 fields at a time

var createInputs = function () {
  $("#ip_div").append('<form id="form"></form>');
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    $("#form").append("<input></input>");
  }
};

$("#btn").click(function () {
  createInputs();
  //create unique ID for each input
  $("#form")
    .find("input")
    .each(function (i) {
      $(this).attr("type", "number");
      $(this).attr("name", "num" + i);
      $(this).attr("id", "num" + i);
      $(this).attr("placeholder", "number" + i);
    });
});
```

inputNum.html

```
<button id="btn"> Add new fields </button>
  <div id="ip_div"> <form action="{{ url_for("inputNum")}}" method="post">
    
  </div>
  <br>

  <button type="submit">Submit for addition </button>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='inputFields.js') }}"></script>
</form>
```

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
        <title>Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Log file ...</h1>
        <script>
           // function for adjusting iframe height to log size
            function resizeIframe(obj) {
              obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
            }
          </script>
        <iframe src="{{ url_for('results') }}" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,why is the button out of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to continue to use flask to run your server in the future, I would suggest creating a forms.py file and run all your forms through python instead of JS, as it works better with flask. Here is a good article on that - https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask_forms.html
After creating the forms, continue reading the article and find out how to use form tags inherited from your app route in your results.html file.